# how to put a custom domain to the imb cloud?

Tags: node.js, cloud, cross-domain, cloud-foundry

I bought a domain in hostinger and I want to place it on my web page that I'm using in ibm, it's a cloudfundry and the code is nodejs, it's currently on but in subdomain bluemix

Answer (score 0):

First, run `cf create-domain` to add the domain to your organization.

Second, add a CNAME to your DNS provider for `*` wildcard for the domain. The CNAME value is your CF’s API (run `cf target` to remind what it is)

Third, map routes to your application with your new domain.